# How to use color palette for Ux and UI design?

Tags: color, color-theory

I am totally newbie in graphic design which from Mobile development.I recently take a look at UX design for mobile.

I see the material design guideline in [Google Material Design Guideline](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette).But I have totally no idea how to use it in the design of my app.

For example I have this Color palette.If I use all this color in my app,it look like the whole app will be red.So which part of the app should use which color?Like button should use 200,the text should use 300(code in the image below),text and so on.Or can you all give me some guideline to organize the color in a specific palette to be use in UX or UI element?Something like best practice?cause it seem like a lot of color pallete out there,which should I choose?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"That's not how this works...it's not how any of this works!" :))

You do not have to use the same color for the entire app.

"***Material Design’s color system***

*In Material Design, a primary color refers to a color that appears most frequently in your app. A secondary color refers to a color used to accent key parts of your UI.*

*Using colors from the Material Design palette is optional.*"

In general, you chose two (primary and secondary) colors that work well together, you even have this example:

[image]

But, just as the guidelines state, there are some apps that prefer to use only one, primary color and shades of it like this one:

[image]

And this is just to summarize:

> All in all, the guidelines don't state to use a single color with all
>   the different variations, they only guide you toward selecting the
>   proper variation for different parts of the app. **At the end of the day, picking out colors for the app is a matter of personal opinion, taste and what the app is for.**

But I think an **all red** app would be pretty disturbing *(but there's also exceptions like the Youtube or Pinterest App since they rely more on pictures/videos with a minimal red color scheme sooo...content is also a factor that you should consider wisely)*

Also, here is a nice web tool to help you chose a primary and secondary color for your app and it will render a preview of how it will look like:

https://www.materialpalette.com/blue/yellow.

[image]
*A blue/yellow combo shown above

**It's especially nice cause it will also allow you to download the XML file that you can place directly in your app! :D**

Comment: wow..this is nice..thanks Alin..I have totally no sense in design..this just open my mind.

Comment: @ken Glad I could help you! Best of luck!

Comment: Can I ask normally how many color use in a single app work the best? 2 will be good??

Comment: @ken yes, basically you try and stand by two, you will have two colors with shades (light/dark variations) plus white (text background) and black/gray for text :D PS: Just like in my Youtube/Pinterest example, depending on your app, it will take in a lot of color from it's content (video/photo).

Comment: shades (light/dark variations)  is which part ya??Sorry for if asking too much..

Comment: @ken Well, take a look at the example with the purple/green theme, they use purple plus two darker variations in the app, the main one (500) is probably used for the App Bar witch isn't shown in the example, the slightly darker (700) is used for the subtitle and the darkest (800) is used for the title background plus the category font color (the "Notes" title).

Comment: In the second example with only one primary color, you have a primary Pesto Green with a lighter and a darker version, each being used for one of the following ; AppBar, Title, Floating Action Button

Comment: ,so the 700 and 800 the place that using in the right hand side photo position is consider a shades?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61118/discussion-between-alin-and-ken).